# Javascript. document.create

Tags: javascript

Is the if statement saying if placeholder is not in document.create(input)? Why is it using document.create.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="john Doe">
<input type="email">
<script>
if( !'placeholder' in document.createElement('input'){
    // do something
}
</script>
```

Comment: That code is so wrong... The `if` is not correctly closed and not using a correct sintax.

Comment: Explain , please, what do you do?

Comment: what does that mean, what do i do, what do i want to do?

Comment: what do i want to do? with the code

Answer (score 2):

It's seems to be trying to perform [feature detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_Feature_Detection) to determine support for [`placeholder` properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-placeholder) on `<input>` elements, which are [new with HTML5](http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder).

The `document.createElement('input')` is used to create an unmodified `<input>` element for the test. And the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) tests for the presence of a property on that DOM element.

Though, it doesn't quite achieve what it seems to be trying. The `!` will act before the `in`, so this ends up testing whether such elements have `false` properties, which they don't.

It'll need another group of parenthesis to ensure that the `in` is evaluated first so `!` can negate its result for the condition.

```
if (!('placeholder' in document.createElement('input'))) {
    // `<input>` elements don't have `placeholder` properties
}
```

Note: It was also missing the closing `)` for the `if` condition.

Answer (score 1):

What your code would do, if it was syntactically correct, would be to check if the browser has native support for the placeholder attribute introduced with HTML5.

The if-statement create a new input element and then check if the newly created element has a placeholder-property. If it has, then the browser support the placeholder attribute.

A syntactically correct example would be:

```
if(!('placeholder' in document.createElement('input'))) {
    // This browser lack native support for the 
    // placeholder attribute, do something
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/eAy3Y/

Answer (score 0):

Try  :

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
if(!('placeholder' in input)){
     input.setAttribute("placeholder", "Your place holder");
}
```

**`document.createElement`** creates a new attribute node, and returns it.

Hope this helps you.